# How can you stop a C1.Win.C1FlexGrid grid from scrolling in window?

Tags: winforms, grid, autoscroll, c1flexgrid

I have C1FlexGrid  grid in windowform, then scroll down so that the lower half of the grid is shown, then click on a control outside the grid, then click on a line in the grid, the grid scrolls up to the top and the wrong row in the grid is selected.
the grid scroll happens before the events fire. I want to stop autoscroll when grid get focus.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out in our custom grid control inherited from C1FlexGrid has a method OnEnter

```
public class FAGrid : C1FlexGrid
{
       public FAGrid();
       //
       protect override void  OnEnter(EventArgs e)
       {
         this.Select(1,1);
          base.OnEnter(e);
       }
}
```

This is a cause of strange behavior. I removed OnEnter method, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my grid's behavior: https://gifyu.com/image/nRtw

I add C1FlexGrid  grid to form in form load event:

private void voucher_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        voucherlib.voucherlib.ListGridDetails[0].Name = "grdCtDkList";
        this.grpCt1.Controls.Add(voucherlib.voucherlib.ListGridDetails[0]);
        voucherlib.voucherlib.ListGridDetails[0].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

I am using C1FlexGrid from ComponentOne for .NET 2.0